# Windows 7 PHone - KeyNotFoundException

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my WP7 app, I'm attempting to navigate from one screen to the other.  The 1st screen contains data that I want to pass to the second string.

On my button click event I have the following code (**updated**):

```
string data = "blahblahblah";

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/popup.xaml?param={0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(data)), UriKind.Relative));
```

On popup.xaml I have the following:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(NavigationContext.QueryString["param"]);
}
```

When I press the button it breaks on the **NavigationContext.QueryString["param"]** stating that there is a **KeyNotFoundException**

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using "=" and you're not encoding the value. Currently the query part is just

```
paramblah blah blah
```

It should be

```
param=blah%20blah%20blah
```

You can include the = directly, and I tend to use `Uri.EscapeDataString` for the value part.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after I took out the spaces and added the Uri.EscapeDataString.  I'll update my example to show what I did...

Comment: E@Jeff: You still haven't got an = sign though... Just edit your format string to include it. (Personally I would just use string concatenation here, mind you.)

Comment: Ahhh... Ok I see what you are meaning now...  Once I added the '=' to the string.format section it is starting to show the data now.